# Passing arguments to a tkinter event callback bound to a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to Python and this is my first time using tkinter.
I'm trying to create an event where if the Enter key is pressed, my function is called passing in arguments (in this case I want to pass in my entry widget).
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
def checkPassword(event):
    # do stuff

from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box
window = Tk()
window.title('Booking System')
frame = Frame(window)
Entry = Entry(frame)
Entry.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", checkPassword)
Entry.pack()
frame.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

The event here is working fine, however I'm having problems when I try to pass in arguments. I've tried

```
def checkPassword(self, event):
    # do stuff

Entry.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", lambda event: self.checkPassword(event, Entry))
```

and get the error NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

And I've also tried

```
def checkPassword(self,event,param):
    # do stuff

import functools
Entry.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", functools.partial(checkPassword, param=Entry))
```

but get TypeError: checkPassword() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

I can't seem to fix either of these, I've looked at the solutions to similar questions on here but can't get any of them to work with my code.

Comment: Is `checkPassword` a method in a class? Is your `Entry.bind` line inside a class method? There isn't enough information here to tell you the correct syntax - please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please explain what you want to do in function checkPassword.
Also please give a different name to your Entry widget. Variables shouldn't be given type names.

Comment: `Entry = Entry(...)` is very bad code. You're effectively deleting the `Entry` widget class and replacing it with an instance named `Entry`. You won't be able to create a second `Entry` widget.

Comment: @Kevin I haven't used classes at all in my code

Comment: That's unusual, because the name `self` is usually used exclusively for functions inside classes.

Comment: @EricLevieil in checkPassword I want to use the .get() function and then use the value in a SQL select statement

Comment: I've actually used entry1, entry2 etc for my entry widgets, I assume this is ok?

Comment: `entry1` is better than overshadowing type names, but it's not quite best practice. Generally, if you have multiple variable names ending with numbers, that's a strong indicator that you should be using a list instead of individual variables.

Comment: entry1 is better but still better is a more informative name, like passwordEntry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second attempt was close, but since `checkPassword` isn't a class method, you shouldn't be prefixing it with `self.`.

```
def checkPassword(event, some_value_you_want):
    # do stuff

Entry.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", lambda event: checkPassword(event, name_of_your_entry_widget))
```

Comment: While this answer is correct for the general problem of including 'some_value_you_want', the extra call layer is not needed when the value is one of the 17 values already included with the event instance. The entry widget is one of them.  See my alternate answer for this particular situation.

Answer (score 4):

Kevin's answer is correct for the general problem of including data along with the event instance, but is redundant when the extra data is the widget causing the event.  Events have up to [17 attributes](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html), including `.widget`, the widget that was the source of the event. (I strongly recommend the tkinter reference that includes the above link.)  The following prints the contents of the entry widget when `return` is hit.

```
from tkinter import *

def checkPassword(event):
    print(event.widget.get())

window = Tk()
Entry = Entry(window)
Entry.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", checkPassword)
Entry.pack()
window.mainloop()
```